# PostgreSQL - проблема импорта .csv

Tags: postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:

```
Ошибка - ������������:  ������ ������������ �������������������� "tempr_operation_id" CONTEXT:  COPY operations_qa_dependency_0, ������������ 18391: "1"
```

Что это за ошибка?

Как ее исправить?

Comment: Либо выкиньте ваш клиент и используйте `psql`, либо переключите постгрес на английский язык. Такое сообщение об ошибке вряд ли кому-либо о чём-либо скажет.

Comment: У меня PostgreSQL

Comment: спасибо. переключу язик на анг